# C++ string != string

Tags: c++, console, dev-c++

I have just started C++ and have some experience with C# so I have some programming experience in general. However, seems like straight away I have been shot down. I have tried looking on Google so not to waste anyone's time to no avail.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    HANDLE  hConsole;
    int k = 5;
    string h;
    string password = "pass";

    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, k);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( GetStdHandle( STD_INPUT_HANDLE ), 0x5B );

    while (h != password)
    {
        printf("This PC is locked\nEnter the password to gain access\n");
        scanf("%s", &h);
    }

    printf("\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Whenever I run this it will get me to enter the password and when I click enter it will acknowledge and then crash asking me to either debug or send information to Microsoft. This started when I added the while loop checking two strings. Have I executed this correctly or have I missed something?

Just in case its not clear. I want the program to compare a string with an input and if they are both the same the program will end.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: Don't use `scanf` for C strings, and especially not for `std::string`. Use `std::cin` (combined with `std::getline` if needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You simply cannot use [`scanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf) to read into `std::string`. This is because `scanf()` is part of C API and it does not support non-POD types. There, `%s` format specifier expects a pointer to character array with size enough to hold the value (which you cannot really guarantee and that's why `scanf()` is even considered harmful) whereas you pass it a pointer to object of type [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) (which is far, far different from a plain array). A good compiler would even issue a warning in this case (if not an error, because non-POD types cannot be passed through `va_list`). Why don't you read into a character array (the C way), or use [`std::cin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cin) instead like `std::cin >> h;`?

Comment: Funny thing is I got that off of a video tutorial - just proves the internet can be the worst source as well as the best.

Comment: @Marshal: True. Take a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/). You might find something useful there.

Comment: @Marshal, Just curious, which tutorial?

Answer (score 2):

As chris suggested, this program can be simplified by using the correct functions:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string password = "pass", input;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "This computer is locked."
                  << "Enter the password to gain access: ";
        std::cin >> input;
    } while (input != password);

    std::cout << "Welcome!" << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1/ As many beginners in C++, you are actually writing C code.
Look for documentation about input/ouput in C++.

2/ How do you compile your code? Your error should have been caught by the compiler

Comment: Currently using DevC++ - the free C++ IDE and press F9 to compile and run the program.

Comment: @vincentB The compiler can't detect that a wrong type's address is passed to `scanf()`! The program will compile, run and crash as the OP described.

Comment: At least VS2010 compiler is warning me:
warning C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe.